# Cannot run cucumber from CLI

Tags: node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

I managed to run cucumber from CLI with

```
node ./node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber
```

but I wasn't able to run it simply with

```
cucumber
```

Windows tried to run it as executable, so it opened some window about missing file association. Is there a way to solve this? Note that I don't want to add nodejs as .js file association, since I am pretty sure the same code won't work on github when travis tries to run the script.

I installed the package with npm.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "cucumber": "^0.8.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `cucumber` globally, i.e. `npm install cucumber -g` This way, npm creates a binary / symlink in some standard 'on-path' directory (i.e., where the executables should be put), so you can run it from command line.

In my notebook (Linux), I run

`sudo npm install cucumber -g`

which creates a symlink

`/usr/bin/cucumberjs -> /usr/lib/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js`

which means I can run it by `cucumberjs` command. If some dependency has `cucumber` command hardwired into it (without the `js` suffix), I'd create another symlink manually.

`/usr/bin/cucumber -> /usr/bin/cucumberjs`

If you run into the following problems, maybe try using `nvm`, not to polute your system folders.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile.

It will add `./node_modules/.bin` to your PATH

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```